# Delete rows based on values or texts

Tags: excel, vba

This code deletes all rows that has the word "Service Tower" only in column D.

I want to delete more rows which also has "Stream play", "Data Set", and many more that contains those text whether they are in column a, b, or c up to z.

```
Sheets("database").Select

Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

With ActiveSheet    
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False    

    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Rows(2).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "D")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "Service Tower" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With

    Next Lrow
End With

ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = CalcMode
End With

MsgBox "Report Completed!"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If .Value = "Service Tower" Or .Value = "Stream Play" Or .Value = "Data Set" Then .EntireRow.Delete
```

This will work if you only have a few to work with.  For a larger number of items it's best to work with an array:

```
delArray = Array("Service Tower", "Stream Play", "Data Set") ' add all the values you want in here
For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
    With .Cells(Lrow, "D")
        For i = 0 to UBound(delArray)  ' arrays are indexed from zero
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = delArray(i) Then 
                    ' if the value matches an array value we'll enter this condition
                    .EntireRow.Delete 
                    Exit For ' if you deleted the row, don't bother to check it against the next item...
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
Next Lrow
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I will explore more and get back if i have some questions